# Display text as notification icon

Tags: android, android-notifications

I am trying to display a notification to the user displaying a counter as the icon instead of an actual icon.

**This is what I'm trying to achieve**

[image]

**What I've tried so far**

```
int myCounter = 0;
setSmallIcon(myCounter); // actually the notification won't even display if its not an actual icon
setTickerText(String.valueOf(myCounter)); // This is actualy something different
setLargeIcon(myBitmapWithText); // I also tried generating a bitmap with text, but it won't display since the resource needs to be in the app-package itself
```

from what I've read, I can use an `AnimatedDrawable` but its really not logical to create like 50 different drawables to accomplish that task, unless I have no other option :)

I'm at the end of my wits with this one, how can I achieve the above result?

Comment: `setSmallIcon` only accept a resourceId so no `Drawable` no `Bitmaps` . I think the only way is to have an icon for each number.

Comment: I guess that's the only solution remaining now